# Resolver main.c: (.text.startup+0x22f): referencia a 'reservar_memoria' sin definir

Tags: c, cuda

Tengo tres archivos que quiero compilar, uno el main.c, otro kernel.cu y otro kerne.h con las cabeceras de las funciones que están en kernel.cu, pero al compilar solo me reconoce la primera función que tengo en kerel.h, el resto me sale el error de compilación de función sin definir.

En kernel.h tengo:

```
#ifndef _KERNEL_H
#define _KERNEL_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
#endif

void select_device();
void reservar_memoria( float *image, int bands, int image_size, float *v_c, float *image_c, float *normM_c, float *out_c);

#endif
```

En kernel.cu:

```
#include "kernel.h"
#include <cuda.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>

void reservar_memoria( float *image, int bands, int image_size, float *v_c, float *image_c, float *normM_c, float *out_c){  
    // Reservamos memoria para los arrays
    cudaMalloc((void**)&v_c, bands*sizeof(float));  
    cudaMalloc((void**)&image_c, bands*image_size*sizeof(float));
    cudaMemcpy(image_c, image, bands*image_size*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice); 
    cudaMalloc((void**)&normM_c, image_size*sizeof(float));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&out_c, image_size*sizeof(float));   
}

void select_device(){ // Devolver el numero de hilos para saber el tamaño de los bloques 
    int count;
    int i, device;
    cudaDeviceProp prop;

    cudaGetDeviceCount(&count);

    for(i = 0; i < count; ++i){
        cudaGetDeviceProperties(&prop, i);

        printf("Device %d, con nombre: %s, con maximo de hilos por bloque: %d, con maximas dimensiones de cada grid: %d, con maximo hilo por bloque: %d \n", i, prop.name, prop.maxThreadsPerBlock, prop.maxGridSize[0], prop.maxThreadsDim[0]);

    }

    printf("Select a device: ");
    scanf ("%d", &device);
    cudaSetDevice(device);

}

// Más código
```

y en main.c :

```
#include "kernel.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include "ReadWrite.h"
#include <sys/resource.h>


int main (int argc, char* argv[]){

// Declaración de variables

    select_device();
    reservar_memoria( image, bands, image_size, v_c, image_c, normM_c, out_c);

//Código
}
```

Al compilarlo la función select_device no da problemas pero todas las que ponga debajo en el archivo kernel.h no las encuentra y sale el mensaje de función sin definir en main.c.

¿Por qué no las encuentra si en todos los archivos está kernel.h o cómo puedo corregirlo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu problema está aquí:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
#endif
```

Tal y como lo tienes puesto, `extern "C"` **solo aplica a la siguiente declaración de función**, que, casualmente, es `void select_device( );`.

Para indicarlo en mas de 1 función, o lo pones en todas ellas (poco práctico), o, mejor aun, lo haces con un bloque:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void select_device();
void reservar_memoria( float *image, int bands, int image_size, float *v_c, float *image_c, float *normM_c, float *out_c);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```